# How to get string input with ReadLine()?

Tags: go

I want to get string from stdio with `func (b *Reader) ReadLine() (line []byte, isPrefix bool, err error)` but my code doent work correctly.

I'm leaning about golang. I want to know about how to get string from standard input with `ReadLine()`

I know, `fmt.Scan` or `Scanner` help me, but I want to use `ReadLine()`

```golang
package main

import (
        "bufio"
        "fmt"
        "io"
        "os"
        "strconv"
)

var sc = bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
var rd = bufio.NewReaderSize(os.Stdin, 1000000)

func nextInt() int {
        sc.Scan()
        i, e := strconv.Atoi(sc.Text())
        if e != nil {
                panic(e)
        }
        return i
}

func nextLine() string {
        buf := make([]byte, 0, 1000000)
        for {
                line, isPrefix, err := rd.ReadLine()

                if err == io.EOF {
                        break
                } else if err != nil {
                        panic(err)
                }

                buf = append(buf, line...)

                if !isPrefix {
                        break
                }
        }
        return string(buf)
}

func main() {
        var s string
        var a int

        s = nextLine()
        a = nextInt()

        fmt.Println(s)
        fmt.Println(a)
}
```

- Result

```
$ ./a.out
test # input
334  # input
test
334
```

```
$ cat in.txt
test
334
$ ./a.out < in.txt
panic: strconv.Atoi: parsing "": invalid syntax

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.nextInt(0xc042056088)
```

I expect the two output should have been same,
but when I use redirection, it didn't work and get different output.

Comment: You _must_ _not_ attach a Scanner `sc` and a Reader `rd` to the same input Stdin. Use one _or_ the other but never both mixed as you do.

Comment: I just want to read first line as a string, and second line as a integer. This is just a experiment. Then, why I must not attach a Scanner `sc` and Reader `rd` to the same input stdin?

Comment: You have two different things reading from the same input and both read differently. It just cannot work. Just use one or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the scanner (you already said you prefer ReadLine()) and change your nextInt() function to call nextLine() like this:

```
func nextInt() int {
    i, e := strconv.Atoi(nextLine())
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
    return i
}
```

(BTW It's not a good idea to panic on bad user input but I assume this is just a test  and you wouldn't do that for production code :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try not using a scanner, perhaps like this
Readline will get the number for you, just convert it

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

var rd = bufio.NewReaderSize(os.Stdin, 1000000)

func nextLine() string {
    buf := make([]byte, 0, 1000000)
    for {
        line, isPrefix, err := rd.ReadLine()

        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        buf = append(buf, line...)

        if !isPrefix {
            break
        }
    }
    return string(buf)
}

func main() {
    var s string
    var a int

    s = nextLine()
    fmt.Println(s)
    s = nextLine()
    a, e := strconv.Atoi(s)
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```